# How to Bind an Event Listener In Azure Queue Storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, event-listener

I have a Queue in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer in which i'm passing a URI , Now the question is i don't want my server to ping every time to check whether something has came to queue or not despite, i want the client itself notify me that some message has arrived in queue, take appropriate action based on that.

i couldn't find any source in java where Event based example has been provided by Microsoft Azure.

Any Sample Working code or Reference in java will do, 
Thanks well in Advance.

Comment: Note that Service Bus Queues have a lot of functionality that Storage Queues do not. See: [Storage queues and Service Bus queues - compared and contrasted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure Queues by themselves don't support this mechanism. Your server would need to poll the queue periodically to see if there are any messages in a queue.

If you don't want to write code for polling, an option would be to use service like [`Azure WebJobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to) or [`Azure Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue). Both of them have `Storage Queue` based triggers and can perform some functionality when a message arrives in a queue. So what you could do is have either WebJob or Function ping your server (assuming it is a web server) when a message arrives in a queue. Please note that these will also constantly poll the queue.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have created a Web Jobs to listen on the queue, which is constantly polling the queue, but my application need it in event driven format, is there anyway using which i can get the WebJobs notified if something has been added to the queue.